# how fancyvrb background color fill completely with fillcolor?

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

I'd like the whole `Verbatim` (`fancyvrb`) block to have a background
color. How do I do it?

The `fancyvrb` package does define a fillcolor -- but that only colors
the area around the margin -- not the background of the block itself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox` with `listings` package seemlessly. There by one can combine the advantages and features of both.  Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
     basicstyle=\ttfamily,
     numbers=left, 
     numberstyle=\tiny, 
     numbersep=5pt     
 }
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{BGVerbatim}{
      arc=0mm,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=0mm,
      left=3mm,
      right=0mm,
      width=\textwidth,
      boxrule=0.5pt,
      colback=yellow,
      spartan,
      listing only,
      listing options={style=mystyle},
      breakable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{BGVerbatim}
abc def {

xyz
\end{BGVerbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use package `listings` instead. It supports page breaks and also `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},frame=single,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{The first section name}
foo
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for exactly the same look as verbatim, check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172705/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the very powerful `tcolorbox` package, in combination with `fancyvrb`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,fancyvrb,xcolor,tikz}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newenvironment{BGVerbatim}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    breakable,
    colback=yellow,
    spartan
  ]%
  \begin{Verbatim}}
 {\end{Verbatim}\end{tcolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{BGVerbatim}[numbers=left,numbersep=6pt]
abc def {

xyz
\end{BGVerbatim}
\end{document}
```

The `numbers=left` option has been added just to show that you can pass `fancyvrb` options to the new environment.

[image]

Comment: it doesn't allow a pagebreak inside

Comment: @Herbert It's easy to add the feature, as I did in my edit

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with the `fancybox` package, which defines the same `Verbatim` environment.

You can define a new verbatim environment, let's say `MyVerbatim` with background and text colors.

```
\newenvironment{MyVerbatim}{\VerbatimEnvironment%
  \noindent\begin{Sbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \begin{Verbatim}
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{Sbox}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\TheSbox}%
}
```

Change `black` and `yellow` to whatever you like.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{MyVerbatim}{\VerbatimEnvironment%
  \noindent\begin{Sbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
  \begin{Verbatim}
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{Sbox}%
  \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\TheSbox}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyVerbatim}
Hello

I have a background!
\end{MyVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the package `fancyvrb` defined the environment `Verbatim`. In my code, I use the invironment `figure` and especially apply `\textcolor` without affecting to the pre-formatting of the text inside `Verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\hlca[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\hlcb[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{SaveVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]{efms}
EFM1: \hlca{R9}  R10i T1  \hlcb{T2}    
EFM2: \hlca{R9}  R10i R11i R12  R13  R14 T1 \hlcb{T5}   
EFM3: R6i \hlca{R9}   R10i R11i R12  R13 R14 \hlcb{R15} T1 T6 T7
EFM4: \hlcb{R6i} \hlca{R7i}  R8i \hlca{R9} R10i R11i R12 R13 R14 T1 T6 T7
EFM5: \hlca{R7i} R8i  \hlcb{R15} T1 T6
EFM6: \hlcb{R6i} \hlca{R7i}  R8i T1 \hlcb{T5} T6  T7    
EFM7: \hlcb{R6i} \hlca{R7i}  R8i R11i R12 R13  R14  T1 \hlcb{T2}  T6  T7
\end{SaveVerbatim}
\fcolorbox{black}{TeaGreen}{\BUseVerbatim{efms}}
\caption{List of 7 EFMs concerning the production of external citrate}
\label{box:7-efms-external-citrate}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Below is the result when running the code.
[image: Verbatim with fill color and text color].