# How can I make lstlisting look exactly like verbatim?

Tags: listings, verbatim

I like the way the verbatim environment looks, and I want to make my lstlistings look like it.

I've tried setting the basic style to `\ttfamily`, but the letter kerning and line spacing seem to be different.  Is there any way in getting it look like verbatim?

Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

This is lstlisting:

\begin{lstlisting}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{lstlisting}

This is verbatim (and what I want):

\begin{verbatim}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

which looks like:

[image]

**Edit**

I tried setting the option `columns=flexible`, but then listings will ignore important spaces in the source code.

Comment: `columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164993/indent-content-of-verbatim-lstlisting-environment-relative-to-containing-envir

Comment: @egreg That works perfectly; would you mind making it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Here is an experiment that shows why all three parameters in `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible, keepspaces=true}` are necessary: [PDF](https://susam.github.io/blob/lab/tex/lst-min-params/lst-min-params.pdf) and [TEX](https://github.com/susam/lab/blob/master/tex/lst-min-params/lst-min-params.tex).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a way; I vastly prefer this to setting `basewidth`, because it doesn't box each character and doesn't need to guess whether the monospaced font uses half em character widths.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  keepspaces=true,
}
\verb|basicstyle=\ttfamily, columns=fullflexible, keepspaces=true|
\begin{lstlisting}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{lstlisting}

This is verbatim (and what I want):

\begin{verbatim}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So there are no visible differences, only that the engine rendering is more flexible with the second approach?

Comment: @csl The difference between `flexible`, `spaceflexible` and `fullflexible` is something I've never really understood. I can't stand the `fixed` style that is horrible with monospaced characters and preposterously awful with variable width fonts.

Answer (score 12):

With the default setting `fixed` for `columns`, `listings` reserves `0.6em` for characters; you need to adjust this to `0.5em` using `basewidth`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fixed,
  fontadjust=true,
  basewidth=0.5em
}

\begin{document}

This is lstlisting:

\begin{lstlisting}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{lstlisting}

This is verbatim (and what I want):

\begin{verbatim}
: paxos.learn ( addr n v -- Ethernet packet )
      2 paxos.pack32          ( addr n v -- addr payload )
      paxos.eth_type.learn    ( addr payload -- addr payload ethtype )
      swap paxos.eth_packet ; ( addr payload ethtype -- ethernet_packet )
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between this and what @egreg commented to my question? (`columns=fullflexible,keepspaces=true`). This also works, but I would like to know why.

Comment: @csl it all depends on how you want spacing to be handled; the explanation is too long for a comment, but you can read Section **2.10
Fixed and flexible columns** of the `listings` documentation to see the difference between `fullflexible`, `flexible` and `fixed`.

Comment: I did, but do the two ways produce the exact same look? I couldn't notice any differences.

Comment: `fullflexible` and `fixed` used with no additional keys for the spacing will produce different results; however, used as in my answer or in `egreg`'s suggestion they seem to produce the same effect. In any case, since egreg's answer now makes mine completely useless, I'll delete this.