# Conflict between verbatim.sty and ltxdoc.cls

Tags: verbatim, package-writing, dtx

I am writing a package which uses the `verbatim` package.

```
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
```

For the documentation I'm using the `ltxdoc` class. So I have to put an `%` character before every line of the documentation. Also when I'm using the `vebatim` environment to typeset code examples like

```
% \begin{verbatim}
% Some Code
% Some other code
% \end{verbatim}
```

`ltxdoc` removes all the `%` at beginning of each line, also inside the `verbatim` environment.

It seems that the `verbatim` package redefines the special `verbatim` environment from the `ltxdoc` class, because when I write

```
% \begin{verbatim}
% some code example
% some other code example
% \end{verbatim}
```

the `%` before `Some code` and before `Some other code` is still there in the produced pdf. So the pdf-output is

```
% some code example
% some other code example
```

But it should be

```
some code example
some other code example
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

### Minimal working example (MWE)

This is an MWE of the `.dtx` file.

```
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{exercises}[2014/04/22 v1.0 .dtx exercises file]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{exercises}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exercises.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \GetFileInfo{exercises.sty}
% \title{The \textsf{exercises} package\thanks{This document
%   corresponds to \textsf{exercises}~\fileversion, dated \filedate.}}
% \author{Roger Jud}
%
% \maketitle
%
% \begin{verbatim}
% \begin{exercise}
%   Calculate $1 + 1 =$
% \end{exercise}
% \end{verbatim}
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintChanges\
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \RequirePackage{verbatim}
  \newenvironment{exercises}{Start}{End}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Comment: Please post an MWE of your `dtx` file, so that people can test what goes wrong with their own eyes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK environment `verbatim` does not support the start of a line with a percent character as in the DTX file format. The following workaround can be done:

1. The environment `verbatim` is written without the percent prefix:

   ```
   \begin{verbatim}
   \begin{exercise}
     Calculate $1 + 1 =$
   \end{exercise}
   \end{verbatim}
   ```
2. The inclusion in the files, generated by `docstrip` can be avoided by using an unused guard:

   ```
   %<*verb>
   \begin{verbatim}
   \begin{exercise}
     Calculate $1 + 1 =$
   \end{exercise}
   \end{verbatim}
   %</verb>
   ```
3. However, the guard disturbs the setting as documentation. This can be
   fixed by a meta comment, the same kind that is also used to exclude the
   driver part from the documentation:

   ```
   % \iffalse
   %<*verb>
   % \fi
   \begin{verbatim}
   \begin{exercise}
     Calculate $1 + 1 =$
   \end{exercise}
   \end{verbatim}
   % \iffalse
   %</verb>
   % \fi
   ```

Complete example:

```
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{exercises}[2014/04/22 v1.0 .dtx exercises file]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{exercises}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exercises.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \GetFileInfo{exercises.sty}
% \title{The \textsf{exercises} package\thanks{This document
%   corresponds to \textsf{exercises}~\fileversion, dated \filedate.}}
% \author{Roger Jud}
%
% \maketitle
%
% \iffalse
%<*verb>
% \fi
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{exercise}
  Calculate $1 + 1 =$
\end{exercise}
\end{verbatim}
% \iffalse
%</verb>
% \fi
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintChanges}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \RequirePackage{verbatim}
  \newenvironment{exercises}{Start}{End}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `listings`

If you consider to use package `listings` instead, then you can keep the percent prefixes, because `listings` can gobble characters from the start of line. The following example uses the verbatim like settings of egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172705/16967) for question ["How can I make lstlisting look exactly like verbatim?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172702/how-can-i-make-lstlisting-look-exactly-like-verbatim) and adds `gobble=2`:

```
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{exercises}[2014/04/22 v1.0 .dtx exercises file]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{exercises}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{dtxverblisting}{%
  \lstset{
    gobble=2,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    keepspaces=true,
  }%
}{}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{exercises.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% \GetFileInfo{exercises.sty}
% \title{The \textsf{exercises} package\thanks{This document
%   corresponds to \textsf{exercises}~\fileversion, dated \filedate.}}
% \author{Roger Jud}
%
% \maketitle
%
% \begin{dtxverblisting}
% \begin{exercise}
%   Calculate $1 + 1 =$
% \end{exercise}
% \end{dtxverblisting}
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintChanges}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \RequirePackage{verbatim}
  \newenvironment{exercises}{Start}{End}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: You were faster. ;-)