How to extract a code listing correctly in .pdf from .dtx file, using package listings?
Question:
How to obtain the ideal result wrt. code listing, shown below, both as screenshot and simplified code?
How to add listings environment to DTX files doesn't seem to solve it for me.
What I have
docwithlistings.dtx:
% \iffalse meta-comment
% License information from .dtx file
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{docwithlisting}
%<package>    [2024/11/10 v1 MWE]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=TeX}
\usepackage{dtxdescribe}
\DisableCrossrefs
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{docwithlisting.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
% 
% \GetFileInfo{docwithlisting.sty}
% 
% \begin{lstlisting}[title=Example,tabsize=4,breaklines=true,frame=single]
%\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{manualIndex}
%\begin{document}
%  \dummy{}
%\end{document} 
% \end{lstlisting}
% 
% 
% \section{Implementation}
% 
% \begin{macro}{\dummy}
% Just a dummy
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand\dummy[0]{hello dummy}
%    \end{macrocode} 
% \end{macro}
% 
% \Finale
\endinput

docwithlistings.ins:
%% Copyright information
%% 

\input docstrip.tex

\keepsilent

\preamble
 Whatever
 
\endpreamble

\generate{\file{docwithlisting.sty}{\from{docwithlisting.dtx}{package}}}

\obeyspaces
\Msg{*************************************************************}
\Msg{* Done!                                                     *}
\Msg{*************************************************************}

\endbatchfile

What it creates via terminal
latex docwithlisting.ins results in a correct .sty:
%%
%% This is file `docwithlisting.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% docwithlisting.dtx  (with options: `package')
%%  Whatever
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\ProvidesPackage{docwithlisting}
    [2024/11/10 v1 MWE]
\newcommand\dummy[0]{hello dummy}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `docwithlisting.sty'.

pdflatex docwithlisting.dtx shows documentation and the listing , but commented-out:

While I'd prefer a result like this:

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=TeX}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}[title=Example,tabsize=4,breaklines=true,frame=single]
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{manualIndex}
\begin{document}
  \dummy{}
\end{document} 
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

Considerations
If I'd comment out in the .dtx file ...:
 \begin{lstlisting}[title=Example,tabsize=4,breaklines=true,frame=single]
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{manualIndex}
\begin{document}
  \dummy{}
\end{document} 
 \end{lstlisting}

it probably will be fine in the .pdf, but also appear in the .sty file. I know, this could be managed somehow via flags, but I (still) struggle to really understand the mechanisms here, let alone using it for predictable outcomes (that's a cause, not a question).
From the documents logic the listing would be some example before digging into the implemention. So it should appear where it is: after </driver>, before \section{Implementation}.

does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172896/ help?

Thank you: it does :) // I was a bit irritated whether or not to modify the .ins file, but it can remain as is. Do you want to post an answer, so I can accept it? Else, I'll be happy to do so.

I found Heiko Oberdiek's answer helpful for verbatim and he also covers usage with listings. Modifying your .dtx and leaving the .ins file as-is (modulo filename change because my test file is called prawf-2.dtx), we have
% \iffalse meta-comment
% License information from .dtx file
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{prawf-2}
%<package>    [2024/11/10 v1 MWE]
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=TeX}
\usepackage{dtxdescribe}
\DisableCrossrefs
\begin{document}
\DocInput{prawf-2.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \GetFileInfo{prawf-2.sty}
%^^A Heiko Oberdiek: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172896/
% \iffalse
%<*verb>
% \fi
\begin{lstlisting}[title=Example,tabsize=4,breaklines=true,frame=single]
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{manualIndex}
\begin{document}
 \dummy{}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
% \iffalse
%</verb>
% \fi
%
% \section{Implementation}
%
% \begin{macro}{\dummy}
% Just a dummy
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand\dummy[0]{hello dummy}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%
% \Finale
\endinput

The guard verb can be anything valid so long as it is not used in your .ins file. So <*aardvark>/</aardvark> would be fine, but <*package>/</package> would not.
This produces the following package file, prawf-2.sty,
%%
%% This is file `prawf-2.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% prawf-2.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% Whatever
%%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\ProvidesPackage{prawf-2}
    [2024/11/10 v1 MWE]
\newcommand\dummy[0]{hello dummy}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `prawf-2.sty'.

and this page of documentation,

